# Printing inside jupyter notebook custom loss function with Keras/TF

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, loss-function

In Keras, if you make a custom loss function in a Jupyter notebook, you can not print anything. For instance if you have:

```
def loss_func(true_label, NN_output):
        true_cat = true_label[:,0]
        pred_cat = NN_output[:,0]
        indicator = NN_output[:,1]
        print("Hi!")
        custom_term = K.mean(K.abs(indicator))
        return binary_crossentropy(true_cat, pred_cat) + custom_term
```

Nothing will print when the function is evaluated.

As a workaround, in case I am doing some debugging, I have found that I can write to a file in a cost function, which can be useful if I want to print something standard like an int or a string.

However, trying to write out a tensor like `indicator` to a file gives the *unbelievably helpful* output:

```
Tensor("loss_103/model_105_loss/Print:0", shape=(512,), dtype=float32)
```

I know TF provides a `tf.Print()` method to print the value of a tensor, but I don't understand how that plays with Jupyter. Other answers have said that `tf.Print()` writes to std. err, which means trying

```
sys.stderr = open('test.txt', 'w')
```

should theoretically allow me to get my output from a file, but unfortunately this doesn't work (at least in Jupyter).

Is there any general method to get a representation of my tensor as a string? How do people generally get around this barrier to seeing what your code does? If I come up with something more fancy than finding a mean, I want to see exactly what's going on in the steps of my calculation to verify it works as intended.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you after, expecting the print command to print about the tensor? That is the most information you can get, name, shape, and dtype.

Comment: I want to see the numerical value of the elements of the tensor.  This is the cost function, so it takes in the network outputs, they have definite values. I just want to see what they are each time the cost function is called when I'm debugging code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below code:

```
def loss_func(true_label, NN_output):
    true_cat = true_label[:,0]
    true_cat = tf.Print(true_cat, [true_cat], message="true_cat: ") # added line
    pred_cat = NN_output[:,0]
    pred_cat = tf.Print(pred_cat, [pred_cat], message="pred_cat: ") # added line
    indicator = NN_output[:,1]
    custom_term = K.mean(K.abs(indicator))
    return binary_crossentropy(true_cat, pred_cat) + custom_term
```

Basically I have added two lines to print the values of true_cat, pred_cat. 
To print something, you have to include the print statement in the tf graph by the above statements.
However, the trick is **it's going to print on jupyter notebook console** where you're running the notebook **not on the ipython notebook** itself.

References:

[How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

[Printing the loss during TensorFlow training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833818/printing-the-loss-during-tensorflow-training)

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print